# Render from controller is working fine in development but not in test

Tags: grails, groovy

I have the following code in my grails app:

```
def list () {
  def roles = principal.authorities*.authority
  def page = roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")? "allcolors": "usercolors"
  if (params.sort == "latest" || params.sort == null) {
    logger.debug("came in if");
    render view: page, model: [colorlist: colorService.colorList()]
  } 
  else
    render view: page, model: [colorlist: colorService.colorListForUser()]
}
```

When I run my application with `grails run-app` the above code works fine. However, when I deploy the war file created by `grails test war target/myapp.war` the above code does not work and errors with "Page not found" even though the debug statement `came in if` still gets printed.

I've tried to run this app in development with `grails test run-app` as well but even then the above does not work. Interestingly, when I run the app in `prod` mode (`grails prod run-app`) everything works fine as well. So it is certainly something to do with the `test` environment

Also, to ensure there aren't any data discrepancies I've changed dev test and prod to point at the same development database.

Could it be that my app has some special setting for test environment that I'm failing to see ...which would cause "render" to not work?

My environment looks like this:

```
    environments {
        development {
            grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        }
        test {
            grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
        }
        production {
            grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        }
    }

And DB config looks like this:

environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myapp?useUnicode=yes&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
        }
        hibernate {
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = 
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myapp?useUnicode=yes&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
            properties {
            }
            hibernate {
            }
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myapp?useUnicode=yes&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
        }
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this or troubleshoot it further??

Comment: seems in test environment you have missing  dbCreate property missing. It should be create-drop or update

Answer (score 0):

run-app runs with the default "development" data source, which is not to be confused with the "test" environment. Check your Config.groovy (edit: and DataSource.groovy) and make sure you have test { } configured within your environments.

More info can be found in the grails documentation here:
http://www.grails.org/Environments

Comment: I am aware of this. but this does not answer the problem I'm trying to resolve. Test is configured properly and the application runs fine on the test environment with the exception of the above piece of code

Comment: Are your development and test dataSources set up in an identical manner? What value are you passing in for dbCreate in each?

Comment: To make sure my development and test are setup same I'm pointing them to the same dataSource (my development). This is not a data problem.

Comment: I would suggest trying to generate a war file using grails dev war target/sift.war and see if you have the same issue. That will help narrow down if it is an environmental problem.

Comment: Apparently, its only happening for test. When I run my app with `grails prod run-app` then also render is working as intended.